Would like to validate whether the AUC equation is correct or not
I found a paper "Chapi, Kamran, et al. "A novel hybrid artificial intelligence approach for flood susceptibility assessment." Environmental modelling & software 95 (2017): 229-245". The paper mentioned the equation of area under the ROC curve (AUROC) is:
$$
AUROC = \frac{ \sum TP+\sum TN }{P+N}
$$
Here, I don't want to argue anything since it is published in a good journal but I would like to have more discussion if the AUC can be easily calculated with the equation.
What I know to calculate AUC is by using integral for area calculation. I tried to find the source of the equation, but I could not find the original one who proposed the equation and well-widely recognized.
I would like to validate if the equation is correct to calculate AUC? I would be glad to appreciate any comments and thoughts, big thanks.

Please [edit] the question to provide more context.  What is the sum taken over?  What are the terms of the sum?
